# Selecionar itens com LongClick, imagebutton

Tags: android, listview, button

Tenho os itens de uma lista, que ao clicar no imagebutton, é enviado uma mensagem ao usuário.

Gostaria de implementar o longclick para que possa selecionar vários e enviar mensagens para vários usuários de uma vez.

Obrigado e segue os códigos:

Presenter com a logica dos clicks:

```
public class InvitePresenter extends BaseAdapter implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, AdapterView.OnLongClickListener{

    private InviteView inviteView;
    private List<UserCommunity> usersList = new ArrayList<UserCommunity>();
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private UsersMySQLiteHelper serviceDB;
    private CommunityService service;
    private SessionManager sessionManager = new SessionManager();
    private EditText search;

    public InvitePresenter(InviteView inviteView){

        inflater = (LayoutInflater)inviteView.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        serviceDB = new UsersMySQLiteHelper(AppController.getAppContext());

        RequestManager.Users(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {

                if (!sessionManager.getInvitedUser()) { //verifica nos preferences se já passou pela hash
                    usersList = new Gson().fromJson(result.get("data"), new TypeToken<ArrayList<UserCommunity>>() {
                    }.getType());
                    sessionManager.setInvitedUser(true);
                }else{ //se já passou, busca do banco os usuários
                    usersList = serviceDB.getUsersToInvite(0);
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        this.inviteView = inviteView;
        this.service = CommunityService.i(inviteView.getContext());
}

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return usersList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return usersList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //recupera o estado da posição atual
        final UserCommunity inviteUsers = usersList.get(position);

        //Cria uma instancia do layout .. na view
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_invite_listview,null);

        TextView txt_Nome = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_nome_invite);
        TextView txt_Email = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_email_invite);
        TextView txt_Distancia = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_distancia_invite);
        ImageButton btn_Share = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.img_invite);

        txt_Nome.setText(inviteUsers.name);
        txt_Email.setText(inviteUsers.email);
        txt_Distancia.setText(Integer.toString(inviteUsers.distance));

        btn_Share.setTag(position);
        btn_Share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String message = "Mensagem de invite";
                usersList.remove(position);
                service.usersInvited(inviteUsers.id,message,inviteUsers.name);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                serviceDB.updateDataBaseInvited(inviteUsers.id,1);
            }
        });

    btn_Share.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            return true;
        }
    });

        return view;
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Log.e("TOP","Doidera");
    }


    public void searchEmail(String q, String company,int invited) {
        usersList = serviceDB.searchEmailInvite(q,company,invited);
        if (usersList != null){
            usersList.clear();
            usersList = serviceDB.searchEmailInvite(q,company,invited);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(AppController.getAppContext(),"Usuário não encontrado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        try {
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            View currentFocus = activity.getCurrentFocus();
            if (currentFocus != null) {
                inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(currentFocus.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        //selecionar vários e enviar
        return true;
    }
}
```

XML dos itens do listview gerado:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/background_light_blue">

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/bynd_teal"
        android:padding="3dp"
        >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/img_invite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_send_white_48px"
            android:background="@drawable/background_btn_submit"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_nome_invite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img_invite"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_invite"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Nome"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_email_invite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_nome_invite"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_invite"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Email"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_distancia_invite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_nome_invite"
            android:text="100000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce terá que definir o momento de enviar. use um botão por exemplo.

**Dentro do click do botão...**

Vai ter que guardar esses valores quando o usuário fizer um click longo no item.

```
message = "Mensagem de invite",
position,
inviteUsers.id,
inviteUsers.name
```

Vai ter que executar esse código, para **todos** os items, quando o usuário clicar no botão de enviar. Ou seja pegue os valores salvos anteriormente e faça um loop neles.

```
for(/* para todos os inviteUsers salvos */){
    usersList.remove(position);    
    serviceDB.updateDataBaseInvited(inviteUsers.id,1);        
    service.usersInvited(inviteUsers.id,message,inviteUsers.name);        
}
```

Depois execute essa linha uma única vez vez.

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Essa solução não é a melhor. Eu apenas sugeri a alterações das classes que você apresentou. Seria interessante que seu método **updateDataBaseInvited** ficasse assim.

```
updateDataBaseInvited(List<inviteUsers> invites, String message)
```

Isso evitaria o loop dentro do seu adapter e deixaria o código menos acoplado.

Comment: Realmente a melhor seria eu utilizar o listview em si. Mas como está montado hoje, tenho que utilizar assim, muito obrigado!